# Iptables rules enabled for allowing icmp/ping for only specific IP address with RHEL7 OS not working

Tags: linux, iptables, icmp

The server where iptables rules are enabled is RHEL 6.4.

From this server, I tried to allow `icmp echo request` from only one specific IP address (host with RHEL7.5 OS).

I used the following rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <ip_specific_node_rhel7.5> -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```

Default policy is `ACCEPT`. So, at the last line, along with other ssh rules allowed, I added the line to block other servers and ports:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

It's not working.

Firewalls are not running on the host with RHEL7.5.

But, from other hosts, rules are working.

Are there any configurations required?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller, It wasn't working. That's why posted the query.

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller, the query was updated as per faced scenario. You may please remove duplicate tag.

Comment: You have the exact same problem as in the already-answered question: the order of the rules matters. Using `iptables -I INPUT` with no rule number after it will add the new rule as the *first* rule, so you'll now have two INPUT rules: 1.) first, drop *everything*, 2.) if any ICMP echo-requests from the specific node still get through somehow, accept them. But they won't get through, because the first rule will already be dropping them.

Comment: @telcoM, I used `append` command and updated the question as well.  I flushed all rules, saved `iptables`  and ran the commands. Still it's not working.

Comment: Could you show your complete ruleset as it exists now? Also note that some of the default rules are tied to specific NICs, and a plain `iptables -L` won't show that; if you use that to view your rules, you may end up misunderstanding how the rules actually work. Use `iptables -L -vn` to get the full output.

Comment: @telcoM, you're correct. Given command helped identify the differences. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's also a sysctl setting named `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all`. If that's set to 1 in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, it will prevent the system from answering to any pings, even if you set iptables to accept absolutely everything.